Can I use geo nodes to turn a mesh back into a mesh?


I have a particle emitter. The particle emitter is set to emit a collection (in yellow), to pick a random mesh from a collection. The TextFX addon generates various text effects like incrementing values, scrambling text etc (on the side ribbon in green). When I use those generated texts as the objects in the particle collection, they do not appear as expected, nor do they appear at all. BUT if I use geo nodes to convert them to a curve I get something close to my desired effect (in red). Unfortunately curves do not show up in render. Is there a subsequent node or operation I can do to get the desired result? Attached is the textfx addon py file, which is a great addon you might enjoy, and the test blend file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qs6aXFaDBqWlYbRg0PwTrO3t9O_QnY07/view?usp=sharing
Blend file

It appears that the particle system doesn't work with text objects. As a workaround you can use a mesh object that instances the text with Geometry Nodes.
For every text object you want to emit, create a mesh object with the Geometry Nodes setup and choose the text object that you want to instance. Then chose the collection of these "Instance" objects to be emitted by the particle system.
Blend file:



It still doesn't work but it's a nice workaround. Oh! it works when I realize instances! great job thanks a ton!!
